# .htaccess url-rewriting help

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm a bit confused on url writing in .htaccess and have a question about rewriting urls.

My first question is I'm trying to do is have a one .htacces to make the urls go from `http://www.website.com/index.php` to `http://www.website.com/Home/`and another .htaccess to go from `http://www.website.com/index.php` to `http://www.website.com/home.html`. Here's a sample code I did to lose the ".php":

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

My second question I'm running into is I have my a tags are set up has `<a href="index.php"></a>` and it shows the the "index.php" not "/Home/" like I want to. Am I suppose to put "/Home/" into the href in order for it to work?

I only build websites has a hobby so I don't know much about htaccess.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how mod_rewrite works and how it is used: mod_rewrite is for rewriting or redirecting requested URIs. So if a URI path like `/Home/` or `/home.html` is requested, mod_rewrite can be used to rewrite these requests internally to `/home.php`.

But to have mod_rewrite do this, you will actually need to request `/Home/` or `/home.html` respectively and not `/home.php`. So `/Home/` and `/home.html` have to be already used in the HTML documents instead of `/home.php`.